# Make a button check if another button was pressed before (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

So my case is:
I have three buttons that lead to the same screen with a "START" button. I need that start button to to a different thing depending on which button was pressed on the first screen.

How it should be:

Niveau1   --   Niveau2   --   Niveau3
--- |---------------|---------------| ---
---+---------- START ---------+---
--- |---------------|---------------| ---
Game lvl1---Game lvl2  ---  Game lvl3

-

How it happens right now:

Niveau1   --   Niveau2   --   Niveau3
--- |---------------|---------------| ---
---+---------- START ---------+---
--- |---------------|---------------| ---
Nothing --- Nothing  ---  Game lvl3

The reason for this is, that the "START" button is connected to Niveau3.
I want to make something similar to this:

```
if Start.isPressed {  
  if Niveau1.wasPressed {   
    start Game lvl1     
  }     
  if Niveau2.wasPressed {     
    start Game lvl2     
  }     
  if Niveau3.wasPressed {     
    start Game lvl3     
  }     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use .tag property by setting different tag number on every button either from storyboard or programmatically.

```
//Programatically set this in either in viewDidLoad
button1.tag = 1
button2.tag = 2
button3.tag = 3

//Assign below action method to all of above button
@IBAction func startButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

   let button = sender as! UIButton
   if button.tag == 1{

   }
   else if button.tag == 2{

   }
   else if button.tag == 3{

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = BooleanLiteralType()
var b = BooleanLiteralType()
var c = BooleanLiteralType()

/* in code for button a when pressed*/
 a = true
if a == true{
/*run code for game a*/
}


/* in code for button b when pressed*/
 b = true
if b == true{
/*run code for game b*/
}

/* in code for button C when pressed*/
 c = true
if c == true{
/*run code for game c*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea. Just go ahead and create a global variable and check for value like you are.

So create a global Int variable like:

```
var nv1 = 0
```

Then when the user taps Niveau1,2,3 buttons, change the int value, for example:

```
nv1 = 1 //if Niveau1 is tapped
nv1 = 2 //if Niveau2 is tapped
nv1 = 3 //if Niveau3 is tapped
```

Then following your code, it would be:

```
if Start.isPressed {
if nv1 == 1 {
start Game lvl1
}
else if nv1 == 2 {
start Game lvl2
}
else if nv1 == 3 {
start Game lvl3
}
}
```